# How do you pronounce 'frappé'?

Tags: pronunciation

How is 'frappé' correctly pronounced? I know that it is from French origin and I used to pronounce it \fra-ˈpā\ (as I've seen on Merriam-Webster). But when my classmates heard me, they corrected me and said it is a one-syllable word without the long a sound. I also hear the local celebrities and other people ordering frappés without the long a. I am from an English-speaking Asian country.

Comment: Here's how OED pronounces it: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frappe

Comment: It's presumably like the fact that you'll hear some Brits drop the final syllable from *cafe* (small restaurant). It's not exactly "wrong", but generally speaking such "premature Anglicization" would be seen as a sign of a poor educational background.

Comment: In general, if you see an accent mark above a vowel (especially a terminal vowel), that vowel is pronounced.

Comment: @Joe Dark You're confusing ODO with OED; it's not guaranteed that they're always consistent.

Comment: If you're in New England, and you order one of these (most of the country calls it a "milkshake") it's pronounced *frap* with one syllable. If it's a cooking term, it's pronounced with two syllables.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite right. The ODO is a useful quick reference but it is emphatically NOT the OED.

Comment: @Peter Shor Does the spelling retain the acute?

Comment: @Edwin: in New England, the milkshake drink is spelled *frappe* with no accent. (And it always contains ice cream, despite the ODO's slightly confusing definition.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh come on! Do you pronounce the Greasy Spoon Cafe in the Balls Pond Road, as though it was the Café Royal in Regent Street? Never mind educational background, I reckon any Londoner would have to be pretty dim not to recognise the difference. When I was a child there was a working-class pronunciation of *caffy* perhaps to rhyme with NAAFI. (*naffy*).

Comment: @Peter Shor Of course, if you say it as *frappe* rather than *frappé* you have turned it from the past participle into a noun - meaning *a strike, or a hit*, rather than *beaten*. The French call their nuclear weapons their *force de frappe*. But they definitely talk about *Champagne frappé*.

Comment: @WS2: Not quite sure what you mean by that. I use both pronunciations myself (***café*** and ***kaff***, never ***kaff-ee***). Usually the former, but I do sometimes use the one-syllable version to deliberately imply a *more downmarket than usual* eaterie/greasy spoon. Part of the reason being that (in my imagination, perhaps) regulars at the greasy spoon are more likely *themselves* to use the one-syllable version. I haven't seen it for years, but I'm sure the café in *Eastenders* is often referred to as the ***kaff***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No I didn't suppose for a moment that you were a person who did not pick up cues of that kind, and I must apologise if it sounded like that. I still sometimes say *kaff-ee*, dating my childhood in the late 1940s, in honour of my father who often said it that way, thinking it was posh. He never went to *the Café Royal* but had he done I'm sure he would have pronounced it *the Kaff-ee Royal*.

Comment: @WS2: *My* father still says ***Poolay** vous Francais?* from time to time, having picked up that pronunciation during the war (presumably from other "uneducated" squaddies, rather than because he simply couldn't hear or articulate the more normal version). Note that when I'm actually *in* France (speaking in French) I don't use the "Anglicized" *Kaff-ay* - I honour the natives by using the somewhat shorter ***é*** sound as in Fr ***bébé*** (which definitely isn't pronounced ***bay-bay***, but Eng ***bay-bee*** is a similar shift to that in to ***kaf-ee***).

Comment: @WS2 I'm British, and I find it surprising that *anybody* would *ever* pronounce it as /kæf/. There is but one pronunciation for me.

Comment: @PeterShor, I've never heard anyone in New England say "frappe" in one syllable. That said, people here don't say "frappé" very much either. We might be in two different places, of course. It would be funny to hear "frappe", because of -- as you said -- the meaning of the word. Imagine hitting a drink. "Frappé" is generally something whipped and makes sense.

Comment: @Isabel Archer: you haven't gone to the right restaurants near Boston, then. See [this pronunciation guide](https://www.bu.edu/mfeldman/Boston/wicked.html).

Comment: @PeterShor, you have a point! But then, you know, there's that ridiculous word _grinder_ in Connecticut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Frappé* is pronounced *fruh-pay*, if it's a frozen, fruity, sherbet-like thing, or a liqueur poured over shaved ice.

If it's a milkshake thing, it's frappe (note the absence of the accent mark). And then it rhymes with *clap*.

Presumably that's the reason for some confusion.

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frapp%C3%A9

Comment: It should be noted that "frappe" in the second sense is a regional thing -- throughout most of the US no one would know what you meant if you asked for a "frap" instead of a "milkshake".  To my recollection, the term is only used (in the US) in some parts of New England.

Comment: What @Hot Licks said. I wouldn't go so far as to say everyone in [Rhode Island & Southeastern Massachusetts](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frapp%C3%A9) is "uneducated", but copying that non-standard regional pronunciation elsewhere would be likely to be seen as slightly "peculiar", if not downright ignorant.